# how to track which transactions are hung on a SQL server

Tags: sql-server

i am developing a monitoring application which determines which transactions on the SQl server are hung. how can i know which applications are hung ? is there some particular API for this ?

Comment: when a transaction is started but is not completely but is in an undefined or stagnant state

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have a look at [Transaction Related Dynamic Management Views and Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178621.aspx), notably `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`

Answer (score 6):

The below gives those sessions that are currently blocking others.

```
SELECT S.*
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests R
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions S
ON S.session_id = R.blocking_session_id
```

Answer (score 3):

On older versions you can also use [aba_lockinfo](http://www.sommarskog.se/sqlutil/aba_lockinfo.html) or the newer beta_lockinfo

Comment: beta_lockinfo is the clear winner. It helped us to track down an issue in a few minutes. It turned out that one of our developers had the habbit to go on a lunch brake while debugging code (which locked tables in the database)! beta_lockinfo shows you the name of the computer in the network and the ID of the exact process that causes your locks and timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

We can also run below command to see open transactions in a database.

```sql
DBCC opentran()
```